# Modularizing Shiny R app code

Tags: r, dataframe, module, shiny, reactive

I am trying to separate the functionality of my Shiny application in order to make it reusable.

I have my **ui. R** file where I define :

```
tabPanel("Unemployed", source("unemployed_select.R", local=TRUE)$value),
```

and in my **unemployed_select.R** I define:

```
fluidPage(
titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),

# Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
fluidRow(
column(4,
       selectInput("man",
                   "Manufacturer:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
),
column(4,
       selectInput("trans",
                   "Transmission:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(mpg$trans))))
),
column(4,
       selectInput("cyl",
                   "Cylinders:",
                   c("All",
                     unique(as.character(mpg$cyl))))
)
),
# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
)
```

My **server.R** file is :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dataset)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# Filter data based on selections
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
data <- mpg
if (input$man != "All") {
  data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
}
if (input$cyl != "All") {
  data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
}
if (input$trans != "All") {
  data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
}
data
}))


})
```

I used the code from a well-known example in R gallery https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html

just to be sure that have no problems of data. Still datatable is not rendering so I guess it has to be a problem with defining inside source file **unemployed_select.R**.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Do ỳou source `make_df.R` in `server.R`?

Comment: Yes Roman using source("make_df.R"). I even tried to create separate scripts inside server folder trying to follow an example in showmeshiny but not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that you need to use `source()` to load your module file, but with Shiny, you need to be aware of *namespaces*. The module and the file it is sourced in must share a namespace, wherein names for things are shared. For example, in your module code, you have this line:

```
column(4,
   selectInput("man",
               "Manufacturer:",
               c("All",
                 unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
```

But you want the module to share the namespace of the file it is included in, so you need to have a way to let the file, which is including the module, know which parts are ids, like "man" and which parts are serious arguments like "Manufacturer:"

So in a Shiny Module, that line would become

```
column(4,
   selectInput(ns("man"),
               "Manufacturer:",
               c("All",
                 unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
```

Here the `ns()` function is used to include the id in the namespace, this will allow your declared id "man" to be usable by the rest of the app.

There is a great guide to namespaces and writing modules in Shiny here:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

The link above points out that you must namespace ids, must make your module fit into a function and call that function using `callModule()` from your `ui.R` file, and must wrap everything in a `tagList` instead of a `fluidPage`.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Farhan. Very useful